# Delete the Last Child by using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
$("input[type = 'button']").click(function() {
  var a = this.id;
  switch (a) {
    case 'div':
    case 'mul':
    case 'sub':
    case 'plus':
      break;
    case 'equal':
      break;
    case 'clean':
    case 'del':
      console.log(a);
      $('#screen:last-child').remove();
      break;
    default:
      $('#screen').append('<p>' + a + '</p>');
  }
});
```

This is my jQuery code.I want to append the id of the selected element when the some button is clicked and delete the last child of the #screen when I click on the button whose id is clean or del.
The append is using on the default and works just fine, but the del function is not working properly.
I tried some methods but still not working.
Thanks for answering my question.

Comment: Could you post your html with the question?

Comment: I think you need `$('#screen > *:last').remove();`

Comment: I should just post my codepen for  someone wants to see the original code.
https://codepen.io/Honesty1997/pen/NRBgaE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `children()`

```
$("#screen").children().last().remove();
```

As you're appending elements dynamically, you might need to use `.on()`

```
$("body").on('click', "input[type='button']", function() {
var a = this.id;
switch (a) {
  case 'div':
  case 'mul':
  case 'sub':
  case 'plus':
    break;
  case 'equal':
    break;
  case 'clean':
  case 'del':
    console.log(a);
    $('#screen:last-child').remove();
    break;
  default:
    $('#screen').append('<p>' + a + '</p>');
  }
});
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  function plus(a, b) {
    return a + b;
  }

  function multiple(a, b) {
    return a / b;
  }

  function minus(a, b) {
    return a - b;
  }

  function division(a, b) {
    return a / b;
  }
  var ope = [];
  $("body").on('click', "input[type='button']", function() {
var a = this.id;
switch (a) {
  case 'div':
  case 'mul':
  case 'sub':
  case 'plus':
    break;
  case 'equal':
    break;
  case 'clean':
  case 'del':
    $('#screen').children().last().remove();
    break;
  default:
    $('#screen').append('<p>' + a + '</p>');
  }
});
});
```

```css
body{
  background-color:#FCFAF2;
}
#calculator{
  margin-top:20%;
  padding-top:25px;
  width:25%;
  border:solid 2px black;
  border-radius:5%;
  background-color:#0D5661;
  padding-bottom:20px;
}
#screen{
  margin:20px 30px 30px 30px;
  height:55px;
  background-color:#0F4C3A;
  border-radius:5%;
   box-shadow:inset 2px 2px 3px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.24);
  padding-top:14px;
  padding-right:10px;
  color:white;
  font-size:20px;
  font-weight:bold;
}
#screen p{
  display:inline-block;
}
#button{
  margin:auto 20px auto 20px;
}
.button{
  width:45px;
  height:34px;
  background-color:black;
  border:none;
  border-radius:3px 3px 10px 10px;
  margin:5px 5px 5px 5px;
  padding:5px 5px 5px 5px;
  color:white;
  display:inline-block;
}
.button:hover {
    box-shadow: 0 3px 4px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.24),0 3px 4px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.19);
}
.two{
  width:100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="calculator" class="center-block text-center container">
  <div id="screen" class = 'text-right'></div>
  <div id="button">
    <input type="button" value="Del" class="button two" id='del'>
    <input type="button" value="√ " class="button two" id='sqrt'></br>
    <input type="button" value="0" class="button" id='0'>
    <input type="button" value="9" class="button" id='9'>
    <input type="button" value="8" class="button" id='8'>
    <input type="button" value="/" class="button" id='div'></br>
    <input type="button" value="6" class="button" id='6'>
    <input type="button" value="5" class="button" id='5'>
    <input type="button" value="4" class="button" id='4'>
    <input type="button" value="*" class="button" id='mul'></br>
    <input type="button" value="3" class="button" id='3'>
    <input type="button" value="2" class="button" id='2'>
    <input type="button" value="1" class="button" id='1'>
    <input type="button" value="-" class="button" id='sub'></br>
    <input type="button" value="0" class="button" id='0'>
    <input type="button" value="AC" class="button" id='clean'>
    <input type="button" value="+" class="button" id='plus'>
    <input type="button" value="=" class="button" id='equal'></br>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You could have waited for OP to respond @Jonathan request

Comment: wow Thanks!I don't quite understand the timing using 'on' function while i see lots of people use it.

Comment: @honesty1997 See my updated answer with example, you were using `child()` not `children()`

Comment: @honesty1997 Is everything ok ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("input[type = 'button']").click(function() {
  var a = this.id;
  switch (a) {
    case 'div':
    case 'mul':
    case 'sub':
    case 'plus':
      break;
    case 'equal':
      break;
    case 'clean' || 'del':
      console.log(a);
      $('#screen *:last-child').remove();
      break;
   default:
      $('#screen').append('<p>' + a + '</p>');
  }
});
```

Comment: OP's code is correct, Does `case 'clean' || 'del':`works?